# Compiled through makefile - no executable generated?

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote a makefile for my C++ program which looks as follows:

```
all: item

item: main.o item.o
    g++ -o item main.o item.o

main.o: main.cpp item.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

item.o: item.cpp item.h
    g++ -c item.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf item
```

Entering 'make' into terminal gave me the following:

```
storm:24% make
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c item.cpp
g++ -o item main.o item.o
```

However, after entering './a.out', terminal outputted:

`storm:25% ./a.out
./a.out: Command not found.`

I'm stumped. I tried putting 'a.out' as well as './a.out' after the 'all' target in the makefile, but I received the same error. Why is it compiling, but not generating an executable? If this helps at all, I'm doing this through remote access (via PuTTY) to a server which runs on Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, after entering './a.out', terminal outputted: ...

Why do you expect to have a `./a.out`? That's the default output of the linker, unless otherwise specified with the `-o` option, as you did with `-o item` in your makefile's action to build the executable program:

```
item: main.o item.o
    g++ -o item main.o item.o
#       ^^^^^^^ !!!
```

Simply call `./item` to run the resulting program, instead of `./a.out`!

Answer (score 2):

When you do the link, you specify the output going into `item` (with `-o item`) therefore, the result should be in a file named `item` rather than `a.out`.

Answer (score 1):

In your makefile

```
g++ -o item main.o item.o
```

the option -o mean that your target file is item.
So I suggest your do this:

```
./item
```